# Making Drawable Image Larger

Tags: android, xml, button, background, xml-drawable

I have the following problem: I want to make drawable image larger.
This is the screenshot: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKq8v.jpg)

My code in this button in activity.xml

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnSoccer"
android:layout_width="480dp"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:textSize="32dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_state_background_categories"
android:drawablePadding="-220dp"
android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_soccer_3"
android:paddingLeft="60dp"
android:text="@string/Fútbol"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textAlignment="center"
android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

This is the custom button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_button_categories_pressed"/> 
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@color/button_focused"/> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner_button_categories"/> <!-- 
default -->
</selector>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the xml attribute `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work in my case, because I only want to change teh size of the drawable (The ball).

Comment: I try with your idea do the button smaller and use:  'android:scaleX="2"'     'android:scaleY="2"' But I think this is not the correct way.